# Webpack Dev Server Constantly Disconnecting

Tags: https, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I'm currently running my `React` application from the `webpack-dev-server` using the following configuration file:

```
// webpack.config.js
/* eslint no-var: 0 */

var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'controller-bundle': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/sym-controller.js'),
    'app-bundle': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/sym-app.js'),
    bundle: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/index.js')
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/html/controller.html',
      filename: 'controller.html',
      chunks: ['controller-page']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/html/app.html',
      filename: 'app.html',
      chunks: ['app-page']
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js(x)?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 4000,
    https: true,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that while the `https` flag for `WDS` is set to `true`, the application continuously throws an error:

```
[WDS] Disconnected!
```

and immediately refreshes the page. (maybe once a second or two)

When `https` is set to `false` this doesn't happen, but I need the application to run with `https` on. I've seen this as an issue on the github issues section for `webpack` but cannot seem to find a clear, straight answer as the why this is happening and how to fix it.

The closest thing I've seen to an explanation is that its due to a mismatch or incomplete handshake between websockets and the dev-server itself. In case I'm able to use it to fix the issue, I have the dev-server's `server.pem` file extracted from the node module package.

---

## Update:

Temporarily resolved by mounting onto a self-signed `express` server using `webpack-dev-middleware`, however I would still like the issue with simply using the `dev-server` to be resolved entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with the codenvy cloud ide.

Try providing a public option with hostname exposed to external env, for example:

```
webpack-dev-server --config=config/webpack.dev.js --public node10.codenvy.io:3000
```

The above change helped me address the issue with respect to hot reload.